# Can I do the ARP spoofing in cloud VPC?

Tags: cloud, vpc, arp

I'm looking for a cloud provider which allow me to run a security training lab, including the network attacks in L2 (e.g. ARP Spoofing).
I need 20 VMs with at least two network interfaces (public and private one), and a VPC which supports all features like the hardware one does.

I've tried GCP already and both ARP and multicast frames are filtered.